# why this error occurs in modelsim for me?

Tags: hardware, system-verilog

Variable 'V' written by continuous and procedural assignments
Variable 'F' written by continuous and procedural assignments.

my code is:

```
   module ALU(input signed [7:0] A,B ,input [2:0] sel ,input Si,input Ci ,output logic signed [15:0] F ,output logic N,Z,V,Eq);
always @(A,B,sel) begin
    F=15'b 0;
    N=1'b 0;
    Z=1'b 0;
    V=1'b 0;

    case(sel)
    3'b 000:begin F=A+B+Ci; end
    3'b 001:F=A+(~B+1);
      3'b 010:F=A<<1; 
      3'b 011:F=A>>>1;
      3'b 100:begin F=A>>1; F[7]=Si; end
      3'b 101:begin F=A<<1; F[0]=Si; end
      3'b 110:F=A*1.5;
      3'b 111:F=A*B;
    endcase
end
assign V=(A[7]==B[7]&&F[7]!=A[7])?1'b1:1'b0;
assign F[15:8]=(V)?((A[7]==1)?8'b11111111:8'b00000000):((F[7]==1)?8'b11111111:8'b00000000);
```

endmodule

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the always block, you are making procedural (variable type) assignments. However, you are also making a coninuous assignment towards the end of the module.

You might try to refactor the continuous assignment in to the always block so that you only have procedural assignment.

Comment: you mean i shouldn't use assign at all?

Comment: @beginner Each `always` block and `assign` statement will become a block of hardware, in your case combinational logic. If you drive a variable from more than one place, then you are effectively shorting the outputs of more than one block of hardware together.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using both a continuous assignment (assign F = ...) and a procedural assignment (in the always block) which is not allowed in the language.

I am guessing that in this case you might refactor the code only to use procedural assignment.

The point is specified in 10.3.2 of IEEE1800-2012. You will see a reference to 'procedural continuous assignment in 10.6, but this is best avoided due to possible future deprecation.